# Changing, what text receive lexer in editor

Tags: netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

For my application on NetBeans-Platform I need, that lexer in my editor recolor the whole text or the whole line, after editing. Now, to nextToken() comes only last edited text, but there not enough for me.
How I can do, that my lexer will get the whole text or the whole line from editor?